# Is the CMB still red shifting?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, cosmic-microwave-background, redshift

If the CMB is red shifted from what used to be infrared and visible light, now shifted to microwave wavelengths, will there be a time where it red shifts so much that it becomes the cosmic radio background from our perspective? or the cosmic long-wave background? If so, how long would that be, and how would we calculate how long it would take?

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your question is yes! We define the [Hubble parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law) $H$ by the equation:

$$H=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$$

Where $a$ is the [scale parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(cosmology)) of the universe, and the overdot indicates the time derivative. Over relatively small times (in cosmological terms) we have can consider the Hubble parameter to be constant. We can then write:

$$Hdt=\frac{da}{a}$$

Solving this simple ODE gives us:

$$a(t)=a_{0}e^{H\Delta t}$$

Where the sub 0 indicates the present time and scale parameter, while the delta indicates elapsed time from the present. The change in wavelength of electromagnetic radiation due to expansion is given by:

$$\frac{\lambda(t)}{\lambda_{0}}=\frac{a(t)}{a_{0}}=e^{H\Delta t}$$

Or in terms of frequency:

$$\nu(t)=\nu_{0}e^{-H\Delta t}$$

From here it's pretty straight forward to figure out what different frequencies (including the CMB background) will be shifted by in the next few million years.